# Jquery radio button show and hide divs

Tags: jquery, radio-button, hide, show

My html and jquery code here. The jquery code performs if value ending with 123 a specify div will show. But i got a problem here. After i clicked on value c123 and d123 and switch back to a and b radio buttons. The showed div will not disappear. How to fix this?

```
<input type="radio" value="a" />
<input type="radio" value="b" />
<input type="radio" value="c123" />
<input type="radio" value="d123" />



<ul id="localBankc123" class="localBank">
  <li>Maybank</li>
</ul>
<ul id="localBankd123" class="localBank">
<li>CIMB Bank</li>
</ul>

$(".localBank").hide();
$("input[value$='123']").click(function() {
 var bank = $(this).val();
        $(".localBank").hide();
        $("#localBank"+bank).show();
    });
```

Comment: Please paste your HTML with `.localBank` divs

Comment: those answers below are good, but I'd also suggest binding to the change() event rather than the click event - so that you don't re-execute your code if the user clicks a radio button that's already selected. eg $('selector').change(function(e){});

Comment: I was thinking to use change but i saw a lot of answers comments that saying change doesn't work in several browsers. is that true?

Answer (score 1):

It would be better if you post the part of HTML with the `.localBank` stuff.

But, if I have understood your problem correctly, it won't hide your div because the handler doesn't get called (the `input` doesn't have a value ending with `123` indeed).

You can attach the handler to all of the `input`s and then, inside the handler, show the div only if the clicked `input` has a value ending with `123`.

Something like this:

```
$(".localBank").hide();
$("input").click(function() {
  var bank = $(this).val();
  $(".localBank").hide();
  if (bank.indexOf(/123$/) {
    $("#localBank"+bank).show();
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$(".localBank").hide();
$("input").click(function() {
  var bank = $(this).val();
  if (bank.indexOf("123") > -1){
    $("#localBank"+bank).show();
  }else{
     $(".localBank").hide();
   }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

please try this code..

```js
$(".localBank").hide();
$("input").click(function() {
    var bank = $(this).val();
    $(".localBank").hide();
    $("#localBank"+bank).show();
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="radio" name="bank" value="a" />
<input type="radio" name="bank" value="b" />
<input type="radio" name="bank" value="c123" />
<input type="radio" name="bank" value="d123" />
   

<ul id="localBankc123" class="localBank">
  <li>Maybank</li>
</ul>
<ul id="localBankd123" class="localBank">
<li>CIMB Bank</li>
</ul>
```